# CatBoostClassifier support within command line version of catboost

Tags: catboost

is it possible to use the [load_model](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier_load_model-docpage/) and [predict_proba](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/python-%20reference_catboostclassifier_predict_proba-docpage/) apis within the command-line version of the catboost?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use catboost binary calc-mode. 
See https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/cli-reference_calc-model-docpage/#cli-reference_calc-model or ./catboost calc --help for more information.